# How to call CefSharp.PostMessage() from Angular JS application

Tags: angular, angularjs, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I'm trying to send message from my Angular application to the windows application using CefSharp browser control. But not able to trigger "post message" which is available in JavaScript as "CefSharp.PostMessage(JSON.stringify(someValue));"

Can you help me with the equivalent command in Angular JS

Comment: Is this Angular or AngularJS? Can you please post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: CefSharp.PostMessage exists in the global scope. It should be accessible from angular via window.CefSharp.PostMessage

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.